# Question without tags

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

How can questions be asked without tags? [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20703657/code-to-identify-element-by-selenium), what happened?

The question did have one tag originally, but it was removed by an edit. Now when I try to remove all tags from a question when editing, I'm not allowed!

Comment: Interestingly, the [revision history](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/20703657/revisions) shows the tag removal, but the [suggested edit](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/3630758) does not.

Comment: @DannyBeckett it's more than that, the tag already appears to be gone in the suggested edit, but the editor unfortunately is getting "credit" for it in the edit history.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

That is what happens when a silly developer (trying to rip out some old legacy hacks that have persisted for 4 years) makes a mistake in the way tags are composed for suggested edits; the bug has been fixed; I will now have fun repairing the damage...

all affected posts should now be fixed. To be clear: no fault here lies with the people reviewing them - they would have looked perfect on screen - it was only when applying the change that it broke.

Comment: OK, I'll have to take your word for it.

Comment: @MrLister or you can listen to [this guy](http://meta.br.stackoverflow.com/questions/279/por-que-alguns-caracteres-nao-funcionam-em-tags), who seems to know what was going on here...

Comment: That's a **beta privado** which I don't have access to. Plus I'm not sure I trust Google Translate enough to draw any conclusions whether he knows what he's talking about or not.

Comment: @MrLister "he" is me. Basically, it was a meta post where I was explaining the recent changes we've made to remove some annoying restrictions on accented characters in tag names - some were allowed, some not - with no sensible distinction between the two.

Comment: Ah, op zo'n fiets.

Comment: @MrLister all Greek to me